# Adding multiple new rows of data to a table based on values in another table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm using asp.net and mvc 3 to create my application. Here is a simplified version of my tables.

My tables are as follows

[STUDENT] (ID, NAME)

[CLASS] (ID, SUBJECT)

[CLASSINSTANCE] (ID, SUBJECT, CLASSID)

[CLASSINSTANCEDETAIL] (STUDENTID, CLASSINSTANCEID, ATTENDANCE)

[ENROLLEDIN] (STUDENTID, CLASSID)

I have relationships between student and class

CLASS **<- 1 to MANY ->** CLASSINSTANCE **<- 1 TO MANY ->** CLASSINSTANCEDETAIL **<- MANY to 1 ->**  STUDENT

STUDENT **<- 1 to MANY ->** ENROLLEDIN **<- MANY to 1 ->** Class

Essentially what I need to do, is evertime I create a new Class, I also need to add a new record in the ClassDetail table with the class id of the class and a matching student id in the enrolledin table for each student. eg. If I created a new classinstance, then I would need to find the classID in that table, and add a new row of data for every student in the ENROLLEDIN table that has a matching classID.

If anyone has any idea how to do this in c# using mvc3 and asp.net, I would be extremely grateful!

PS. I imported my database using the entity framework with my model in a data access layer folder if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to create the new `ClassDetail` records on C# using Linq you could use:

```
var class = classInstance.Class;
var newDetails = from s in class.Students
                 select new ClassDetail
                 {
                     ClassInstance = classInstance, 
                     Student = s
                 };
foreach(ClassDetail cd in newDetails)
{
    ClassDetails.Add(cd);
}
```

This assumes that the Student<->Class many-to-many relationship was mapped directly and the `EnrolledIn` table was not mapped to an entity.  If it was, try this:

```
var class = classInstance.Class;
var newDetails = from ei in class.EnrolledIn
                 select new ClassDetail
                 {
                     ClassInstance = classInstance, 
                     Student = ei.Student
                 };
foreach(ClassDetail cd in newDetails)
{
    ClassDetails.Add(cd);
}
```